# Problem while using <force:canvasApp> with VF Page via lightning component

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

I have added  lightning app into visualforce page i am getting error like "Something has gone wrong. Cannot read property 'length' of null. Please try again." could some one help me on this.

I have created simple application called "CanvasLightning" and created component called "CanvasLightningcomp".

### **CanvasLightning.app**

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
   <aura:dependency resource="c:CanvasLightningcomp"/>    
</aura:application>
```

### **CanvasLightningcomp.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
  <force:canvasApp developerName="ICM" namespaceprefix="" width="999" height="400" maxHeight="infinite" maxWidth="infinite" parameters='{"ICMRequest":[{"sysId":null,"sObjplural":null,"showBreadCrumb":false,"redirectUrl":null,"operation":"ViewList","inputJSON":null,"entityType":"Contract","entityName":null,"contractTypeName":null,"clientName":"Salesforce"}]}'/>
  <h1>Hello Canvas</h1>
</aura:component>
```

I have added this lightning app into visualforce page like this:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeLightning />    
<!-- <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" /> -->
<script>
    //var baseUrl = 'https://icmsfdemo-dev-ed.lightning.force.com'; 
    $Lightning.use("c:CanvasLightning", function() { 
        $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:CanvasLightningcomp",
        {},
        "lightningCanvas",
      function(cmp) {
        console.log('comp loaded' +cmp);
      });
    });
</script>    
<div id="lightningCanvas" />
</apex:page>
```

Finally when try to access the page, getting following Error:
[image]

Looking forward to get some help on it.

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Please use the native Visualforce component for this instead.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_vf_component_ref.htm

Comment: Doug, Thanks for your response, but the native apex page is not supporting resizing of canvas in lightning UI. when we see this page in lightning, at that time the content is hidden, or there are multiple scrollbars. Well Its working with SF classic UI without any issue. And it is something which need to integrate with lightning importantly.

Comment: @SreenivasKotapati Why don't you directly drag the component than having it again lightning out

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Can you please elaborate that what do you mean?

Comment: Using the force:canvasApp component inside of a Visualforce page via LC for Visualforce bridge is not a configuration that has been tested AFAIK because VF already has a native component for this. If the apex:canvasApp VF component is not functioning correctly for you please open a case on that. Getting force:canvasApp working inside of VF is likely to be given a very low priority.